# Update ParseInstallation Cached

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Is there a way to update the parse installation cached or on disk?

I can't seem to assign a new parse installation, from cloud code, to the current Installation on my device. I'm sort of manually changing the parseInstallation via Cloud Code.

Note: fetchInBackground doesn't work. And I wanted to get the updated version from the server.